# С днём сисадмина!

Tags: обсуждение

Всех причастных поздравляю с этим замечательным праздником - Днём Системного Администратора!

Ура!

Как именно сисадмины празднуют? Отвечаю ниже.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ежегодно в России проходят туристические слёты, куда приезжают только админы.

Знаю 2 таких крупных площадки: Орёл и Ярославль. Не успели присоединиться - в следующем году приезжайте. Успели - велкам!

В этом году Всеросийский Слёт Системных Администраторов проводится в 17-й раз, а начиналось это всё давным-давно в Калуге. Адреса и сайты не привожу, чтобы не устраивать здесь рекламу.

С праздником ещё раз!

Comment: Поздравлю всех вас!